# Run MongoDB commands from PHP files which are stored on a webserver

Tags: php, mongodb, exec

I'd like to know the way to run MongoDB commands from PHP files which are stored on a webserver. What I'm trying to do is to import a database from a dump file and then -with the MongoDB service running- to call an external .jar file which uses that MongoDB files I've just imported, while the service is running. I've alredy installed the MongoDB Driver for PHP (I'm testing this on xampp server for Windows) but I can't find any examples that indicate the exact process of running usual MongoDB commands (in my case, the 'mongoexport'). As far as I know, the MongoDB service is initiated by:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing [database commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) with the [binary tools](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/components/#binary-import-and-export-tools) that ship with MongoDB. Tools such as `mongoexport` and `mongodump` are not executed through the driver. Rather, they are standalone C++ programs.

You can certainly execute those through PHP, but doing so would require executing the binary through something like [popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or a library such as Symfony's [Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). If you're running PHP on Windows, I would recommend the Symfony component, as it has a bit of extra code around PHP's `popen()` interface to improve Windows compatibility.

On the off chance you want to execute database commands through PHP, you'll want to use [MongoDB::command()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php), unless the command has a helper method on the MongoDB or MongoCollection object (such as [MongoCollection::aggregate()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)).